# Javascript submit a form according to input tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a form as shown below:

```
<div>
<form id="speed_form" action="/dashboard/speed" method="get">
<select name="speed">
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
  <option value="4">4 Rate</option>
  <option value="5">5 Rate</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="123456" />
</form>
</div>
```

I use this js code to submit above form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
        $("#speed_form").submit();       
});
</script>
```

I want to send a `GET` request, to the page, `/dashboard/speed?speed=name&id=value`. The **name** is hidden by `input` tag. And I should take `option value` into `GET` method !!!

Could you help me to realize it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: there is no input with name `id`

Comment: also add your javascript code in a [dom ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) like `jQuery(function () {
    $("select[name=speed]").change(function () {
        $("#speed_form").submit();
    });
})`

Comment: Ajax could be used to send the Get or post requests.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
<input type="hidden" name="123456" value=4 />
```

by:

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="4" />
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="123456"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.ajax` and create the url and data by yourself like so:

```
$(function()
{
    $('form').on('submit', function(event)
    {
        var elem = $('input[type="hidden"]');

        var data = 'speed=' + $(elem).attr('name') + '&id=' + $(elem).val();

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: "/dashboard/speed",
            data = data
        });

        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace you code like this

```
<div>
<form id="speed_form" action="/dashboard/speed" method="get">
<select name="speed">
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
  <option value="4">4 Rate</option>
  <option value="5">5 Rate</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="name" value=123456/>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=4 />
</form>
</div>
```

And change your java-script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
        $("input name:id").val($("select[name=speed]").val());  
        $("#speed_form").submit(); 


});
</script>
```

Please look to these links [val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)  [change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/). Use class or id attribute to select dom. Remember you can use AJAX in situation like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is only function binding problem 
you need to write your Jquery code within  $(function()

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
   $("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
    $("#speed_form").submit();       
   });

}
</script>
```

if you got any error reply me install web devloper tool in your browser to see error

Answer (score 0):

Replace your script section with this code. it may be helpful to you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("select[name=speed]").change(function(){
    this.form.submit();      
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div>
<form id="speed_form" action="/dashboard/speed" method="get">
<select name="speed" id="speed">
  <option value="1">1 Rate</option>
  <option value="2">2 Rate</option>
  <option value="3">3 Rate</option>
  <option value="4">4 Rate</option>
  <option value="5">5 Rate</option>
</select>
<input type="hidden" name="123456" id="hidden"/>
</form>
</div>

//Most simple
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#speed").change(function(){
        var value = $(this).val();
        $('#hidden').val(value);
        $("#speed_form").submit();
});
</script>
```

I recommend always assign id